# How to create backup in directory format

Tags: backup, postgresql

Creating backup in directory format using

```
pg_dump -f "sba" -Fdirectory --jobs=32 --verbose sba
```

throws error

> ```
> pg_dump: error: could not stat file "sba/282168.data.gz": value too large
> ```

How to fix it ?

Server is Postgres 12 running in Debian Linux 10 under WSL
Client is pg_dump from Postgres 15 running in Windows 11

282168.data.gz file size is 6.2 GB

Comment: Is your pg_dump the 64-bit version or 32-bit? Is it a Windows .exe or is it running in WSL?

Comment: It is 64 bit (there are no 32 bit executables in Postgres 15). It is windows .exe file from official postgres 15 distribution. It is running in Windows 11 and in windows file system.